# Why are there only two cores in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, task-manager, windows-xp-embedded, quad-core

I'm running Windows XP 32-bit on an Intel Q9650 quad-core CPU.

In Device Manager, I see four cores. It's OK. However in Task Manager, I can only see two cores. Are only two cores used? If so, why are there are four cores in Device Manager?

I'm confused. Does anyone know this problem? Is it related to 32-bit Windows? Perhaps I need to install some patches?

More information:
I run Windows XP Embedded in KVM. It's convenience for me to do some simple tests. Are there any problems with XPE in virtualization environment? Or are there any differences between XPE and XP?

Here are the snapshots:

[image: Device manager]

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: Are you looking at the "CPU usage" chart? That's not connected to the amount of cores you have. Under "CPU history", is "one graph per CPU" selected?

Comment: could you post a task manager snapshot please? Furthermore, if you right-click on a running process and select "Set affinity..." from the context menu - what CPUs are you offered to select?

Comment: I have attached the snapshots.

Comment: it might have been helpful to mention the virtualisation originally. Not being familiar with that virtualisation software, I would wonder if it presents each core to guests as a separate CPU.

Comment: Robert Moir's comment is just the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use MSconfig to check # of processors allowed, be sure all the boxes are Unchecked. Hit OK, OK if you make changes.

Msconfig> BOOT.INI tab > Advanced Options

.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Robert Moir's comment is just the answer. Thanks a lot!

```
it might have been helpful to mention the virtualisation originally. Not being familiar with that virtualisation software, I would wonder if it presents each core to guests as a separate CPU. – Robert Moir 2 hours ago
```

Answer (score -3):

Based on [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/888732) direct from Microsoft, the 32-bit version of Windows XP only supports a maximum of 2 processors (cores).

Comment: processors are **not** the same as cores. XP is quite happy to support quad core processors.